# Energy bond and number of photons

Tags: energy

If I am given the energy bond of a specific bond in a molecule, is that the energy of one photon? and if I have, for example 2 bonds like this, there will be needed 2 photons, etc...? (In other words- does each photon required to break one bond)?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Good question, but no, it is not like that. One should not regard the chemical notation literally. In the nitrogen molecule N$_2$, there is a covalent bond between the atoms. One should not regard the three sticks in the diagram as sticks that could be broken seperately. Without going into details, the molecular orbitals are similar to those in molecular oxygen O$_2$ with just two sticks in a chemical diagram.

A more physics way of looking at photodissociation is to regard the equipotential surfaces. There is the ground state, where the binding energy as a function of interatomic distance of is like a Morse potential.

When the molecule absorbs a photon, it is excited to a higher equipotential surface. If that is a dissociative state, the atoms fly apart.

[image]